# How do i solve JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature RS256

Tags: express, jwt, rs256

I have been stuck at `JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature` while trying to verify it.

The auth middleware where i am verifying

```
module.exports.authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
const tokenParts = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
console.log(tokenParts)

// verifying that the token from authorization header is in correct format
if(tokenParts[0] === "Bearer" && tokenParts[1].match(/\S+\.\S+\.\S+/) !== null){
    try {
        const verification = jsonwebtoken.verify(
            tokenParts[1],
            PUBLIC_KEY,
            {algorithms: ["RS256"]}
        )

        req.jwt = verification
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(401).json({
            success: false,
            message: "You are not authorized auth"
        })
    }
} else {
    res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        message: "You are not authorized",
    })
}

}
```

I have successfuly generated the private and public keys here is the function

```
const genKeyPair = () => {
const keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096, // bits - standard for RSA keys
    publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs1', // "Public Key Cryptography Standards 1" 
        format: 'pem' // Most common formatting choice
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs1', // "Public Key Cryptography Standards 1"
        format: 'pem' // Most common formatting choice
    }
});

// Create the public key file
fs.writeFileSync("keys/id_rsa_pub.pem", keyPair.publicKey); 

// Create the private key file
fs.writeFileSync("keys/id_rsa_priv.pem", keyPair.privateKey);
}

genKeyPair()
```

When i copy the token that is generated during login or registration and add the private key and public key to jwt.io online with algorithm, i get signature verified
[image]

What could possible be the problem?